# Is mobile JavaScript different from desktop JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sounds crazy, I know. But I'm getting a weird math/array related bug that only occurs on mobile phones.

It could possibly be a jQuery bug, but I'm not sure.

I was doing some number crunching when I noticed that one item kept on returning NaN, specifically the first item in the array.

```js
var taxBrackets = {
  //if this number or higher
  0: 0.95, //5%
  1950000: 0.90, //10%
  3300000: 0.80, //20% 
  6950000: 0.77, //23%
  9000000: 0.67, //33%
  18000000: 0.60, //40%
  40000000: 0.55, //45%
};
var exp = [
  30000, //rent
  1098, //phone
  5143, //wifi
  15000, //commuter pass
  1500, //health
];


function calculate(hoursPerWeek, daysPerWeek, trainFare, wage) {
  data = [];
  var taxRate = 1;
  data['total'] = Math.floor(wage * hoursPerWeek * 4);
  data['tax'] = data['total'] * 12;
  for (key in taxBrackets) {
    if (data['tax'] < key) {
      break;
    }
    taxRate = taxBrackets[key];
  }


  data['total'] = data['total'] * taxRate;
  data['total'] = data['total'] + (daysPerWeek * 4 * (trainFare * 2));
  data['monthly'] = data['total'];
  data['yearly_total'] = data['total'] * 12;

  for (var n = 0; n < exp.length; n++) {
    data['monthly'] = data['monthly'] - exp[n];
  }
  data['weekly'] = Math.floor(data['monthly'] / 4);
  data['daily'] = Math.floor(data['monthly'] / 30);
  data['taxRate'] = Math.round((1 - taxRate) * 100) + "%";
  return data;
}
res = calculate(24, 3, 480, 1000);

for (let key in res) {
  console.log(key, res[key])
}
```

Anyway, you can see it for yourself here. https://jsfiddle.net/frogg616/vg6r0v4g/

The chart with taxrates of 5% shows as NaN on mobile phones, but works on a computer.(tested on iPhone SE iOS 10 and iPhone 5S iOS 9)

So, my question is are mobile JavaScript and computer JavaScript different? If so, where can I find more information on their differences?

Comment: Why do you declare `data` as an Array, if you use it only as an Object? Also all your variables (except arguments) are global, if you do it a lot on your page, anything could be messed up.

Comment: Note, no value is `return`ed from `calculate()` function call. _"one item kept on returning NaN"_ Where is `NaN` returned?

Comment: @guest271314 okay, now try

Comment: @TrevorWood `Uncaught ReferenceError: exp is not defined`. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @guest271314 okay, i'm pretty sure i got everything now. Sorry!

Comment: Your fiddle worked fine on my phone, tested with two unrelated browsers. I don't have an iPhone though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that keys in Javascript objects aren't ordered. The order in which the cases are processed is not defined by the language, so there is no guarantee that the 5% bracket will be checked before the others. If no value is assigned to `taxRate`, it will be `undefined`, and performing any further arithmetic operations on it will result in a `NaN` result.

(This isn't specific to desktop vs. mobile browsers. It just so happens that the desktop browser you were using was behaving differently than Safari on iOS.)

Don't use an object for this. Use a series of `if` and `else` statements, e.g.

```
if (income < 1950000)
  taxRate = 0.95;
else if (income < 3300000)
  taxRate = 0.90;
...
else
  taxRate = 0.55;
```

Comment: Actually, objects in JS (at least in browsers) are ordered, although it's not supposed to be relied on.

Comment: @DerekBrown yes it would because in OP's `if (data['tax'] < key) { break; } taxRate = taxBrackets[key];` If the first `key` meets the condition, `taxRate` would be undefined for the remaining of the code.

Comment: @DerekBrown Specifically, if no value was ever assigned to `taxRate`, performing any subsequent arithmetic operations on it would result in a NaN.

Comment: Or you could define the brackets as an array of objects like `[{bracket: 0, rate: 0.95}, {bracket: 1950000, rate: 0.9}, ...]`, and then continue using a loop in the `calculate()` function. Although if it were my code I'd move that part out of the `calculate()` function and create a separate `getTaxBracket(income)` function called from within `calculate()`.

Comment: @Kaiido actually in my jsfiddle taxRate is default 1 or 0%. I updated my post with that code included

Comment: @duskwuff hmm, even if I set `taxRate = 1` as default inside the function. It still returns NaN. However if I remove the first index in `taxBracket` and set `taxRate = 0.95` default it works on my phone, which fixes my problem but it still doesn't explain why it was returning NaN in the first place. Just to clarify `It still returns NaN even if I set taxRate = 0.95 default inside the function`

Answer (score 3):

Javascript is interpreted by a component of the web browser known as a runtime.  Different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Safari Mobile, etc) use different runtimes, which could lead to differences in program behavior.  While there is a general agreement about how many features of the Javascript language should work, there are many slight differences in implementation- especially when it comes to "modern" features in the latest specifications of Javascript.

As you could imagine, these differences can be painstaking to detect and fix- which has led to the entire field of cross-browser testing.  You can read more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing) (MDN is generally very good when it comes to functionality documentation.

<strike>As for your specific case, I would look at a package called [math.js](http://mathjs.org/).  Javascripts' default `Number` type has a limited precision (read more about floating point numbers [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic)).  Math.js gets around this by using "safer" types for storing big numbers, which would likely fix the `NaN` values you are seeing.</strike>

@duskwuff's answer seems to be correct in this specific case.  The ordering of the object keys are not guaranteed- so there is a case where the loop terminates before defining taxRate.

Comment: Why would loss of precision on big numbers lead to NaN values? In the OP's case the numbers aren't particularly big: no more than eight digits to the left of the decimal place.

Comment: My understanding is that it was a calculator- so this could be the case for some inputs.